# Invoke same API in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to fetch data from exposed API and insert data into DB.
API returns JSON which contains two objects: Page object and Activities array object.
In Page object, it can be seen that there are 400 pages, so I need to invoke API 400 times and store Activities into DB for each call.
Since invoking API 400 times is very time-consuming I wanted to improve speed using multithreading, however, the code is behaving weirdly, passed page number looks like is not going in sequence and in the console I see almost immediately that index reaches numberOfPages 400.

I tried bellow and I am not sure what can be the issue:

```
private static Map<Integer, ActivityResult> activities = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ActivityResult>();

public static void fetchActivities(){
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    String activityResponse = runRequest("/activity/", first_page);
    ActivityResult ar = (ActivityResult) gson.fromJson(activityResponse, ActivityResult.class);
    activities.put(first_page, ar);
    int numberOfPages = ar.getPaging().getPages();
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(first_page +1);
    for(index.get(); index.get() < numberOfPages; index.incrementAndGet()){
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 System.out.println(index.get());
                 String tmpResponse = runRequest("/activity/", index.get());
                 activities.put(index.get(), gson.fromJson(tmpResponse, ActivityResult.class));          
            }
        });
    }
    es.shutdown();
    System.out.println(activities.size());
}
```

runRequest method is invoking API using okhttp3, it should be thread safe.

Comment: Hmm. So, you are creating 400 threads. Think over it.

Comment: As can be seen in the code snippet, I set pool size to 20.

Comment: @ShaileshPratapwar 20 threads. 400 tasks.

Comment: can you share what you see in the console?

Comment: Something like this: http://example/activity/?client_id=foo&signature=bar&page_=1
10
256
257
400
400
1
276
276
276
400
400
400
400
400
400
400
400
400
400
400
400
http://example/activity/?client_id=foo&signature=bar&page_=256
400
http://example/activity/?client_id=foo&signature=bar&page_=400
400
http://example/activity/?client_id=foo&signature=bar&page_=400
400
http://example/activity/?client_id=foo&signature=bar&page_=400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(first_page +1);
for(index.get(); index.get() < numberOfPages; index.incrementAndGet()){
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             System.out.println(index.get());
             String tmpResponse = runRequest("/activity/", index.get());
             activities.put(index.get(), gson.fromJson(tmpResponse, ActivityResult.class));          
        }
    });
}
```

You are not using the atomicity of `AtomicInteger`. The for-loop executes very quickly on the parent thread and submits all 400 tasks. 20 will start soon (but not necessarily immediately) and the other 380 will get queued up. `index` has been  incremented all the way to 400. The tasks have been *submitted* but they may not start until some indeterminate point in the future.

The tasks are then started and use the *latest value* of `index`. Any tasks which are in the queue (in your case tasks 20-400) will probably all start after the for-loop has completed and `index.get` will return 400 for all of these tasks. The first 20 tasks will likely start mid-way through the for-loop and will get a random set of values.

The correct code should look something like this (I've also converted `Runnable` to a lambda):

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(first_page + 1);
for(int i = first_page; i < numberOfPages; ++i){
    es.submit(() -> {
       int page = index.incrementAndGet();
       System.out.println(page);
       String tmpResponse = runRequest("/activity/", page);
       activities.put(page , gson.fromJson(tmpResponse, ActivityResult.class));          
   });
}
```